# Generating HTML table with data that must correspond to ox oy axes headers

Tags: javascript, python, html

Is there any way i can EASILY generate an html table with horizontal headers(1row) and vertical headers(1st column) with the provided **list of objects** that is the data inserted in the table, when:

```
container.name = 'whirlpool' #unique set of attr for all objs makes the 1st row 
container.version = '8.1' # gather a set of this to form headers (1st column)
container.status = 'FAILED' # this is put inside the formed grid into corresponding cell, if no such cell, we provide default 'not tested'
```

so, if we had t.name = 'whirlpool' as the container, it would look for all objects to form a row with it like this:

```
            8.1          8       7
Whirlpool   FAILED       PASS    <not tested>
Keccak      <not tested> PASS    PASS
```

I think i am overengineering that i try to wrap this kind of functionality. as I have written a ton of code that firstly 
a)go over a loop of all my container objects to form a set of names
b) go over a loop of all my container objects to form a set of versions
c) start taking container name as to see on what versions it has been tested and form a list that later is inserted into template HTML.

I think it is a quite common question to want to have such a 'result table' but i could not find the answer so far, and the ton of my code happen to generate inappropriate results(there is wrong status for the corresponding row and column header in the crosshair of them)

Comment: If you really want a html output, I strongly advise you use something like **lxml**, it has a **html.builder** which you can build your table dynamically and convert to html with ease.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the solution was quite simple:

In order to create such excel-like table generated with values containing three entities: header ox, header oy, result, you just:

1) Form the unique headers both for oy and ox:

```
ox_headers = sorted(list(set([report.version for report in reports])
oy_headers = sorted(list(set([report.sample_name for report in reports])
```

2) Iterating over our unique headers as to form an html_grid:

```
data_to_html_sample = []
for oy_header in oy_headers:
    ox_row = [oy_header]
    for ox_header in ox_headers:
        ox_row.append(next((report.result for report in reports if (report.name == oy_header and report.build == ox_header)), "< not tested >"))
    data_to_html_sample.append(ox_row)
```

3) Now we have a list of rows that correspond to our headers and we use Jinja2 as our templating tool:

```
import jinja2
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")

env = Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=True)
template = env.get_template('table_results.html')



output = template.render(ox = ox_headers  oy = oy_headers, data = data_to_html)

with open("results.html", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(output)
```

And the Jinja2 template in the templates folder looks like this:

```
<table class="tg">

    <tr>
        <th class="tg-031e"> Name / Version <br></th>
        {% for item in ox %}
        <th class = "th-031e">{{item}}<br></th>
        {% endfor %}

    </tr>



    {% for row in data %}
        <tr>
            {% for item in row %}
            <th class = "th-031e">{{item}}<br></th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>


    {% endfor %}


</table>
```